# Chartjs force horizontal bar to start from the lowest value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using the [HorizontalBar](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#horizontal-bar-chart) option of the Chartjs plugin and I have values between -15 and 115. When my percentage value is 0.75 I'd like the bar to fill from -15 to 0.75.

I have set the properties `beginAtZero` false (which I believe it only works in Y axis..) and `fill` as true but it does not work.

```
datasets: [
{
    data: [percentage],
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
}]
```

....

```
options:
{
    scales:
    {
        xAxes: [
        {
            ticks:
            {
                beginAtZero: false,
                min: min,
                max: max
            }
        }],
    }
}
```

As you may see in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72f3g16c/)** the black bar starts at 0 and should start at -15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a **floating bar** since **Chart.js v2.9.0**, a feature that was merged into [chartjs:master](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) with [pull request #6056](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6056). Individual bars can now be specified with the syntax `[min, max]`.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Floating Bar</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        canvas {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="50"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
    
      var percentage = 0.92;
      var min = -15;
      var max = 115;
      
      window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'horizontalBar',
                data: {
                  datasets: [{
                      data: [[min, percentage]],
                      fill: true,
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
                  }]
                },
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                              min: min,
                              max: max
                            }
                          }],
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```